Trying to call setWaitTime() on an Attendee instance I created and the data isn't being modified
template<typename T>
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const T& data);
        Node(const T& data, Node<T>* next);
 
        T getData() const;
        void setData(const T& data);
        Node<T>* getNext() const;
        void setNext(Node<T>* next);
 
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T>* next;
};


template<typename T>
class LinkedDeque {
    public:
        LinkedDeque();
        // LinkedDeque(const LinkedDeque& ogQueue);
        ~LinkedDeque();
 
        Node<T>* getNodeAt(const int& pos) const;
 
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool enqueue(const T& entry);
        bool enqueueFront(const T& entry);
        bool dequeue();
        bool dequeueBack();
        T peekFront() const;
        T peekBack() const;
        int size() const;
 
    private:
        Node<T>* front;
        Node<T>* back;
        int count;
};

class Attendee {
    public:
        Attendee();
        Attendee(const int& waitTime);
 
        int getWaitTime() const;
        void setWaitTime(const int& waitTime);
 
        bool operator<(const Attendee& rhs);
 
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Attendee& rhs);
 
    private:
        int waitTime;
};

for (int i = 0; i < reg.size(); i++) {
    Node<Attendee>* curr = reg.getNodeAt(i + 1);
    Attendee attendee    = curr->getData();
    attendee.setWaitTime(waitTime);
    if ((i + 1) == stop || (i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
        waitTime += 2;
    }
}

attendee is stored in a templated LinkedDeque class within a Node's data field. Not sure how to go about modifying it's data directly. I tried declaring Attendee attendee = curr->getData() as refernce, but I'm just presented with an initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue error. It's late and I've been staring at my screen for a while now. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Attendee attendee    = curr->getData(); takes a copy. The original Attendee object is not altered.

We need a [mcve]. Something that can be copy/pasted into a compiler and reproduce the issue.

@user12002570 not very minimal but this is what I could do at the moment.. https://pastebin.com/MRWH58Dc

@Botje Yes. This is why I tried to declare it as a reference. Does this mean I'd have to modify the Node class, too? As well as any other instance of Node within my program? See pastebin link above.

Edit your question with the added code. Questions should be self-contained.

@xvymnp you would most certainly have to return something that can be modified, usually a reference. Note that references are also more efficient than copies -- and I don't think you're using threads, so that shouldn't cause issues.

The data isn't being modified because you are modifying a copy. curr->getData() returns a copy of Attendee.
Even a change such as:
Attendee& attendee = curr->getData();
Will not work because curr->getData() returns a temporary as shown in its class. This temporary cannot be lvalue assigned.
template<typename T>
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const T& data);
        Node(const T& data, Node<T>* next);
 
        T getData() const; <— returns a copy of T.
        void setData(const T& data);
        Node<T>* getNext() const;
        void setNext(Node<T>* next);
 
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T>* next;
};
Return T by reference instead:
T& getData() const;
Now calls such as curr->getData() returns the original instance of Attendee. You can refer to it using an lvalue reference:
Attendee& attendee = curr->getData();
